# Set Position of iText Element

Tags: java, position, itext

I need to generate a PDF with some pieces of text and Images. But it's not like an ordinary document (with full text), nor it has a standard position for the elements. It's supposed to be something that's custom and designed by the user.
So, I want to know what is the best way to set "manually" the position of a `Chunk` or `Image` (accordingly to what the user chose), and how to be able to put the text on top of the image (like a second layer).

I need to fill the page with 4 x 5 of this modules, but some modules can have different sizes than 1 x 1. 
Example:

[image: Example of a module]

The yellow part is an image and on top it can have also an image. 
The black and gray parts are small images/flat rectangles with some text on top. The middle rectangle has 2 different fonts.
I have everything stored in a `HashMap` with necessary texts, images, bounds and positions. Now I need to reproduce that in a PDF file.

**NOTE:** Some modules, lke I said, can have different sizes, and according to the size, it can have more than one image in also different positions (but always inside the yellow bound).

Comment: *"accordingly to what the user chose"* - which options do you want the user to have?

Comment: Which iText version do you use? The legacy 5.5.x or the new 7.x? iText 7 even has high level API methods for custom layouts while iText 5 would require you to use medium level API methods.

Comment: @mkl I am using the 5.5.12 version. So, you recommend me to use iText 7? Are the other methods the same? (or do I have to change everything I have already?)

Comment: *"So, you recommend me to use iText 7? Are the other methods the same?"* - If you start with a new project, I definitively recommend using iText 7. If you are maintaining an old, iText 5 based project, it depends on how much you want to change anyways. iText 7 is a complete rewrite with a different (IMO improved) API, so you'd have to change all your iText related code to completely move to iText 7. You might also consider using both versions side-by-side instead.

Comment: Ok, thank you @mkl ! I will look into that